# Python Regex Syntax

Tags: python, regex, function, expression

I have the following function:

```
def handleRequest(self, command, ident, ip, duration=0):
    if not re.match("^[0-9]+$", ident) or not re.match("^[0-9.]+$", ip) or \
        (duration and not re.match("^[0-9]+$", duration)):
        print ("Unknown command")
        return

    if command == "DOTHIS":
        reactor.callInThread(self.func, ident, "./DOTHIS.sh", ip, 0, command)
    elif command == "DOTHAT":
        reactor.callInThread(self.func, ident, "./DOTHAT.sh", ip, 0, command)
    elif command == "DOTHAT":
        reactor.callInThread(self.func, ident, "./DOTHING.sh", ip, duration, command)
    elif command == "DOMORETHINGS":
        reactor.callInThread(self.func, ident, "./DOMORETHINGS.sh", ip, duration, command)
    else:
        print ("Unknown command")
        return
```

I use this function to execute certain scripts on my server.
My problem is the correct syntaxis of the to be executed commands (DOTHIS, DOTHAT etc.)
It must have something to do with regex.
The commands can have several parameters (e.g. DOTHIS 127.0.0.1).

No matter how I query the command, the result is always "Unknown Command".

Could anyone give me an example of a command with the right syntaxis (including a couple of parameters).

Thanks!

Comment: Which unknown command is being printed? The first or the second `print ("Unknown command")`

Comment: I'm not having problem with your code! Could you post some examples of how are you calling it?

Comment: Basically I make a terminal connection to my server and give in the command I want. An example of this is PING 127.0.0.1 80 (this should execute PING.sh and start a ping to 127.0.0.1 port 80). Also, I think it's the first "Unknown command" Tom.

Comment: What does `ident` mean here?

Answer (score 0):

`re.match("^[0-9.]+$", number)`

matches all strings that contain only numbers.

So you should be able to do:

```
def handleRequest(self, command = '0', ident = '0', ip = '0', duration='0'):
```

use `help('re')` to find out about what the characters mean.

Answer (score 0):

in handleRequest what are you sample inputs ?

i.e for command, ident?

assuming ip='127.0.0.1', duration ='10'

FYI, This condition always make the output False if the string contains just number.

```
(duration and not re.match("^[0-9]+$", duration))
```

Answer (score 0):

This assumes all arguments are strings, but this should work:

```
import re

def handleRequest(self, command, ident, ip, duration=0):
    returnEarly = 0
    if not re.match("^\d+$", ident):
        print ("Invalid ident")
        returnEarly = 1
    if not re.match("^[\d.]+$", ip):
        print ("Invalid ip")
        returnEarly = 1
    if (duration and not re.match("^\d+$", duration)):
        print ("Invalid Duration")
        returnEarly = 1

    if returnEarly:
        return

    if command == "DOTHIS":
        print ("DOTHIS")
    elif command == "DOTHAT":
        print ("DOTHAT")
    elif command == "DOTHING":
        print ("DOTHING")
    elif command == "DOMORETHINGS":
        print ("DOMORETHING")
    else:
        print ("Unknown command")


handleRequest("", "DOTHIS", "11", "127.0.0.1", "10") # works
handleRequest("", "BADCOMMAND", "11", "127.0.0.1", "10") # fails on command
handleRequest("", "DOTHIS", "11C", "127.0.0B.1", "A10") # fails on arguments
```

I used the "\d" regex shortcut in python for numbers, I also made each check explicit so if it does fail you know why. If you are passing in arguments that are not strings you can use str(argX) to convert it to a string before checking. I used python 2.7 to test this.

**EDIT:**
I should also point out, that I lazily did not make this method part of a class, and just passed in the empty string for self.